# How do I get the lint level from a Visitor given a Block?

Tags: rust, lint, internals, visitor-pattern

For various reasons I use a Visitor for the HIR tree traversal instead of
relying on the lint context to walk the tree. However, this means my lint
ignores `#[allow/warn/deny(..)]` annotations in the source. How can I get this
back?

I know of `ctxt.levels`, but those don't appear to help. The other functions
(like `with_lint_attrs(..)` are private to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no solution with the Rust we had, I [created](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/31562) the necessary callbacks in Rustc: With tonight's nightly, our `LateLintPass` has another `check_block_post(..)` method. So we can pull the Visitor stuff into the lint, and add a new field of type `Option<&Block>` that is set in the `check_block(..)` method and unset in the `check_block_post(..)` if the field is equal the current block, thus ignoring all contained blocks.

Edit: The code looks as follows:

```
use syntax::ast::NodeId;

struct RegexLint { // some fields omitted
    last: Option<NodeId>
}
// concentrating on the block functions here:
impl LateLintPass for RegexLint {
    fn check_block(&mut self, cx: &LateContext, block: &Block) {
        if !self.last.is_none() { return; }
        // set self.last to Some(block.id) to ignore inner blocks
    }

    fn check_block_post(&mut self, _: &LateContext, block: &Block) {
        if self.last.map_or(false, |id| block.id == id) {
             self.last = None; // resume visiting blocks
        }
    }
}
```