# How to suppress the warning for "drop_with_repr_extern" at a fine granularity?

Tags: rust, suppress-warnings

I am currently experimenting with multi-threading code, and its performance is affected by whether two data members share the same cache line or not.

In order to avoid false-sharing, I need to specify the layout of the `struct` without the Rust compiler interfering, and thus I use `repr(C)`. However, this same `struct` also implements `Drop`, and therefore the compiler warns about the "incompatibility" of `repr(C)` and `Drop`, which I care naught for.

However, attempting to silence this futile warning has proven beyond me.

Here is a [reduced example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9aadf3dfdcca551fef75&version=stable):

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct Simple<T> {
    item: T,
}

impl<T> Drop for Simple<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Simple::<u32>::default());
}
```

which emits `#[warn(drop_with_repr_extern)]`.

I have tried specifying `#[allow(drop_with_repr_extern)]`:

- at `struct`
- at `impl Drop`
- at `mod`

and neither worked. Only the crate-level suppression worked, which is rather heavy-handed.

Which leads us to: is there a more granular way of suppressing this warning?

*Note: remarks on a better way to ensure that two data members are spread over different cache lines are welcome; however they will not constitute answers on their own.*

Comment: I have a hunch that this is due to the way the lint is constructed. Will look at the code when I get to my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is [near the end of rustc_lint/builtin.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/015d3b70929a31af48d056a8e05d113e362339e9/src/librustc_lint/builtin.rs#L1144):

The lint does not walk the crate, instead using `ctx.tcx.lang_items.drop_trait()` to look up all `Drop` trait implementations within the crate. The annotations are only picked up while walking the crate. I've stumbled upon the same problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284646/how-do-i-get-the-lint-level-from-a-visitor-given-a-block). So unless someone changes the lint to actually walk the crate and pick up `Drop` `impl`s as it goes, you need to annotate the whole crate.

Comment: Thanks! It's annoying that it's implemented this way, but at least I know there's no best way for now.